# Images not blitting

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a simple program to stitch multiple images together. Some of the images in question are quite large. However, I cannot get the following code to work:

```
out = py.Surface((width, height), flags=py.SRCALPHA)

pos = 0

for i in images:
    r = out.blit(i, (0, pos))
    print(pos, r)
    pos += i.get_rect().size[1]
```

In theory, the follwing code should take the loaded images from the `images` list, and blit them to an output surface of a predetermined width and height (calculated based off of the combined heights and maximum with of the images). However, that isn't the case.

```
0 <rect(0, 0, 256, 44096)>
44096 <rect(0, 0, 0, 0)>
46112 <rect(0, 0, 0, 0)>
48128 <rect(0, 0, 0, 0)>
50144 <rect(0, 0, 0, 0)>
52160 <rect(0, 0, 0, 0)>
```

As you can see from the program output, the first (very large) image blits fine, but the other images do not.

I cannot work out why this is happening. The full code for this script is [here](https://github.com/Lightning3105/Legend-Of-Aiopa-RPG/blob/12b41d5b45910177e6ce01b9ff350653e430747d/Map%20Maker/ImageStitcher.py). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps it is because your rects after your first have width/height of 0. That makes it impossible to see. Try adding some width and height to those rects. If this is it let me know so I can post an answer, but I haven't tested it so I don't want to post an answer if I'm not sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is different from the one in your link, but it works fine in my tests.

I would simplify it a bit more to something like this:

```
width = max(i.get_rect().width for i in images)
height = sum(i.get_rect().height for i in images)

out = py.Surface((width, height), flags=py.SRCALPHA)

pos = 0
for i in images:
    r = out.blit(i, (0, pos))
    pos += i.get_rect().height
```

Maybe the height calculation in your actual code is a little bit off? If a `blit` returns an empty `Rect`, it means nothing could be drawn on the destination `Surface`.

Comment: This all works fine with small images, but when I blit a very large image (256x44096) first, the other smaller images do not blit. The height calculations are fine - I've tested simply drawing rectangles of the correct size onto the surface, and they are all in the right places. Thank you for the simplified code though (the extra code down the link is just so that the user know what's going on).

Comment: Maybe you hit a limit of what SDL on your machine can handle :-/ maybe you should give PIL a try, then...

Answer (score -2):

Part of the problem is this:

`r = out.blit(i, (0, pos))`

You are always blitting the images to x=0.  How wide is the width?  You need to do something like:

`Xpos = i.get_rect().size[0]`
`Ypos = i.get_rect().size[1]`

and then use them when blitting.  Then compare them to the width.  Also, does this code work (the whole loop), because after you have added a couple of large images, the width variable is going to be large, so unless the other images are very wide, I don't see how it will work: `if i.get_rect().size[0] > width:`